# node.js mongo queries are not the same as mongosh queries? How do you troubleshoot mongo queries written in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I come from a mysql background.

Currently experimenting with node.js and mongo.

When learning mysql:

- you start with the command-line client and you learn how to write queries.
- you move up to the application layer, and you write those EXACT same queries.

When learning mongo, I followed the same pattern:

- I started with mongosh and learned how to write queries.
- I move up to the node.js layer.

Now this is where it get's strange:  I haven't found a library that allows me to write mongo queries EXACTLY as I would write them in mongosh.
mongoose and the mongodb library both let me write queries that "accomplish the same thing", but I have to write something slightly different.

This is concerning.  With mysql, when I get unexpected results, I can cut and paste each application layer query into the command-line client to double check what is happening.

But what do node.js developers do? You've written node.js code that "accomplishes the same thing", but not something that you can paste into the command-line client.

Bugs often come down to tiny typos.  How do you check what node.js is sending to mongo?

Comment: You can pass objects directly to the Mongo Node.js client library for insertion, for example. You don't have to convert objects to strings at all. That probably explains why the Node.js environment seems to operate different to the Mongo shell command line.

Comment: for very simple tasks it may make things easier, but when the queries become complex and have multiple steps, then the debugging issue comes up.   I'm looking for a way to discover the mongo query that node.js is sending to mongo.   Ideally I'm looking for a way to cut out the lost-in-translation middle man.  I already know the query I want to send to mongo, why do I need to experimentally discover how to re-create that query in node.js

Comment: Try using the newer mongosh shell, it is node.js based.

Comment: ok, that is useful!   On one of my mongo servers I can paste my node.js code directly into mongosh, it connects to the other mongo server and executes the query!  I just need to copy all the lines that have anything to do with the mongo connection.   This is a good trouble shooting tool, it addresses the problem is reverse... but that's still very useful to know, thanks